# Method endsWith() not working in android java coding

Tags: java, android

I was creating a simple calculator with android. I was implementing a solution where if an user presses any operator at the end of a number, and presses 'BtnEqual', it'll trim any mathematical operator if present at the end of the string. The string is retrieved from a TEXTVIEW variable, Tv.
My problem is, even I've used endsWith() method, it's trimming ANY CHARACTER FROM THE END of the string, even if it's not a mathematical operator. I'll implement mathematical operations on 'BtnEqual' later on, but I'm stuck here wuth this problem. Following is the contents MainActivity.java file:

```
package org.betaapps.simplecalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
TextView Tv;String Disp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    int[]Btn_Id={ 
        R.id.Btn0, R.id.Btn1, R.id.Btn2, R.id.Btn3, R.id.Btn4, R.id.Btn5,
        R.id.Btn6, R.id.Btn7, R.id.Btn8, R.id.Btn9, R.id.BtnClear, R.id.BtnDecimal,
        R.id.BtnDivide, R.id.BtnMultiply, R.id.BtnSubtract, R.id.BtnAdd, R.id.BtnEqual
    };
    for(int i : Btn_Id){
        ((Button)findViewById(i)).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    Tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtScreen);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Disp=Tv.getText().toString();
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.Btn0:
            if(Disp.equals("0")) {                      //If user pressed 0 and screen is 0
                Tv.setText("0");
            }
            else {                                          //If screen contains other numbers, then append 
                Tv.append("0");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Btn1:
        case R.id.Btn2:
        case R.id.Btn3:
        case R.id.Btn4:
        case R.id.Btn5:
        case R.id.Btn6:
        case R.id.Btn7:
        case R.id.Btn8:
        case R.id.Btn9:
            if(Disp.equals("0")) {                  //If user presses digits and screen has 0,replaces
                Tv.setText(((Button)v).getText().toString());
            }
            else {                                                      //If screen contains other than 0
                Tv.append(((Button)v).getText().toString());
            }
            break;


        case R.id.BtnAdd:                                               //If operator is pressed after an operator, toast warning
            if(Disp.endsWith("+") || Disp.endsWith("-") || Disp.endsWith("*") || Disp.endsWith("/")) {                          //If user presses operator after an operator
                Toast.makeText(this, "+ not allowed at this point!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Tv.append("+");                                     //last character is number, so append
            }
            break;
        case R.id.BtnSubtract:
            if(Disp.endsWith("+") || Disp.endsWith("-") || Disp.endsWith("*") || Disp.endsWith("/")) {                          //If user presses operator after an operator
                Toast.makeText(this, "- not allowed at this point!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Tv.append("-");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.BtnMultiply:
            if(Disp.endsWith("+") || Disp.endsWith("-") || Disp.endsWith("*") || Disp.endsWith("/")) {                          //If user presses operator after an operator
                Toast.makeText(this, "* not allowed at this point!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Tv.append("*");
            }
            break;
        case R.id.BtnDivide:
            if(Disp.endsWith("+") || Disp.endsWith("-") || Disp.endsWith("*") || Disp.endsWith("/")) {                          //If user presses operator after an operator
                Toast.makeText(this, "÷ not allowed at this point!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Tv.append("/");
            }
            break;  
        case R.id.BtnClear:
            Tv.setText("0");//Everything will be 0 again
            break;


        case R.id.BtnEqual:
            if(Tv.getText().toString().endsWith("+") || Tv.getText().toString().endsWith("-") || Tv.getText().toString().endsWith("*") || Tv.getText().toString().endsWith("/"));
            {
                Tv.setText(Tv.getText().toString().substring(0, (Tv.getText().toString().length()-1)));
                //Removing last operator
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can put simple java code for this, pass a string as param and return o/p string. Write unit test for this kind of sensitive logic

Comment: @jiteshmohite can you please elaborate or give me a small example on this? I'm new in android and I've learned only the basics.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I'll implement mathematical logic later on in my code, The main problem i'm facing now is removing the last operator if user presses 'BtnEqual' button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the semicolon (`;`) after your `if` statement.

Your code:

```
if (condition);
{
     // trim character
}
```

The `trim character` code block will not be constrained by the `if` condition, and will be executed regardless.

It should be:

```
if (condition)
{
    // trim character
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution worked perfectly. I'm sorry I didn't noticed that syntax error in my code earlier :)